# Are there any differences between if (!x) and if (x == nullptr)?

Tags: c++, std

Ignoring user-defined operator overloads, are there any cases where `if (!x)` would behave differently from `if (x == nullptr)`. Or, conversely are there any cases where `if(x)` would behave differently from `if (x != nullptr)`.

e.g. Are there any types in the standard library for which `!x` would behave differently from `x == nullptr`.

Note: I'm aware this is very similar to many other questions on SO, but believe it still warrants it's own question. I've given my justification for why here: [Are questions about NULL sufficiently different from questions about nullptr?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389346/are-questions-about-null-sufficiently-different-from-questions-about-nullptr)

Also, on that meta-post, L. F. pointed out that `std::optional<T*>` is one such case. However, I'm interested to know whether there are any others, especially with primitive and/or pointer types.

Comment: Doesn't `std::optional<T*>` qualify as a user-defined operator overload?

Comment: @Eljay How so? The standard library defines [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) and [operator !=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp), no user overload required.

Comment: They are not core-code, they are operator overloaded in the standard library.  I wasn't sure where you were drawing the line for "Ignoring user-defined operator overloads".

Comment: @Eljay Ah, yes. That is why I specified "user-defined" - the standard library overloads can be expected to behave rationally, but the user can define strange overloads.

Comment: Depends on the type of `x`.  Comparing an `int` with `nullptr` will not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They differ for most primitive types.

boolean for example:

`!true` is valid whereas `true == nullptr` is ill formed.

Comment: Or for `std::string_view`: `!x` doesn't compile, but `x == nullptr` exhibits undefined behavior

Comment: wouldn't true == nullptr result in nullptr getting converted to a pointer, which then gets converted to false?

Comment: @DanielMcIntosh: There is no conversions here [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/508f7a60562c8d4b) of compilation error.

Comment: AFAIR nullptr was added to the core to be implicitly convertible to any buit-in pointer type but to no numeric type. It is supposed to be a universal pointer literal as 0 is supposed to be a universal numeric literal. Since bool and std:: nullptr_t are not convertible to each other, the built-in comparison operators are supposed fail at compilation.